# How to include Multiple IFs in Excel formula?

Tags: excel

I have the formula below that has two IF Statements however it is given an error. Any help is appreciated.

```
=IF((AND(B11>65,D15>65)),Sheet!D$47,VLOOKUP(D15,Sheet!$A$2:$K$51,4,FALSE)),IF((AND(B11>61,D15>61)),Sheet!D$44,VLOOKUP(D15,Sheet!$A$2:$K$51,4,FALSE))
```

What I am trying to Achieve is the following:

IF B11>65 and D15 >65 Then select value from D$47. IF B11<65 and D15<65 Then Select value from D$44. Else VLOOKUP(D15,Sheet!$A$2:$K$51,4,FALSE))

Comment: Your second `if` must be inside the first `if`. So if the first `if` is "False" then it executes the inside `if` like:  `if(AND(B11>65,D15>65),Sheet!D$47, IF(AND(B11>61,D15>61),Sheet!D$44,VLOOKUP(D15,Sheet!$A$2:$K$51,4,FALSE)))` The way you have it written is nonsense. It would be like `=Sum(A1:A5)Sum(B1:B5)`

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Egan Wolf. I have added the details in the question

Comment: Thanks JNevill. The formula is giving an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple IF() calls embedded such as this:

```
=IF(AND(), Sheet!D$47, IF(AND(), Sheet!D$44, VLOOKUP())
```

The complete form in your case would be:

```
=IF(AND(B11>65,D15>65), Sheet!D$47, IF(AND(B11>61,D15>61), Sheet!D$44, VLOOKUP(D15,Sheet!$A$2:$K$51,4,FALSE)))
```

Basically, this uses the 'Else' clause as a means to add additional clauses. It is possible to do it the other way around but I personally find that harder to read.